# how to dynamically change the href attribute with the array of id's?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have these elements and I want to change the id's dynamically using the fetched id array via server which I have categories (Ex: `["category 1", "category 2","category 3","category 4","category 5", "category 6"]`). I don't know how to do this nothing seems to work.

```
<li role="presentation" class="active categories"><a href="#all" aria-controls="all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ALL</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#chicken" aria-controls="chicken" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CHICKEN</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#fish" aria-controls="fish" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FISH</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#turkey" aria-controls="turkey" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TURKEY</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#miscellenous" aria-controls="miscellenous" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">MISCELLANOUS</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#frozen" aria-
```

Comment: You haven't given us any info about what the fetched id array even IS. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for your question! and Welcome to Stack Overflow, please feel free to check out the links in my previous comment, it might help you to provide more details in your question so that someone may be able to help answer it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`So, from your question, I understand that you want to give each of the elements the id with the value in the fetched array.

So for the first `<li>` element, the id would be `category 1`.
If this is what you are asking for, the solution is to grab the required elements

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul>
      <li role="presentation" class="active categories"><a href="#all" aria-controls="all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ALL</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#chicken" aria-controls="chicken" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CHICKEN</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#fish" aria-controls="fish" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FISH</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#turkey" aria-controls="turkey" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TURKEY</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#miscellenous" aria-controls="miscellenous" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">MISCELLANOUS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#frozen" aria-controls="last" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">LAST</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>




let fetchedArray = ['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5','cat6'];
    $('li').each((i,el) => {
      $(el).attr('id',fetchedArray[i]);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i did the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change ids, you can use a for loop to iterate through the elements and change them.

```js
const categories = ["category 1", "category 2", "category 3", "category 4", "category 5", "category 6"];
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++) {
  let el = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i];
  el.id = categories[i];
  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<li role="presentation" class="active categories"><a href="#all" aria-controls="all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ALL</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#chicken" aria-controls="chicken" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CHICKEN</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#fish" aria-controls="fish" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FISH</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#turkey" aria-controls="turkey" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TURKEY</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="categories"><a href="#miscellenous" aria-controls="miscellenous" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">MISCELLANOUS</a></li>
<!--
<li role="presentation" class="categories">
  <a href="#frozen" aria-
-->
```

The above iterates through the `lis` and attaches the ids to the elements in `categories`. Then it prints the element to the console so you can see how their ids have been set.

Answer (score 0):

I added new class to the elements and then changed the href this way

```
<a class="category-text" href="#chicken" aria-controls="chicken" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CHICKEN</a>
```

```
var new_id = [];var category_name =[];
for(i in categories){
    new_id[i] = categories[i].id;
    category_name[i] = categories[i].name;
}

var i = 0;var new_name;
$(".category-text").each(function(i){
    new_name = '#' + new_id[i];
    $(this).attr('href', new_name);
    $(this).text(category_name[i]);
    i=i+1;
});
```